# PySpark: parsing multiple JSON and knowing which file led to which row

Tags: json, pyspark

I am parsing multiple JSON files with `spark.read.json("/mnt/folder/2020/October/*/*.json")`, this returns me a DataFrame with the information aggregated from all of these JSON files.

How can I know the path to the JSON file that contains the information in a specific row?

I searched the documentation for a parameter in `read.json()`, hoping to find a `include_src_file` parameter or something, but I am not finding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain file name info using the `input_file_name()` function:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

dataframe.withColumn("input_file", input_file_name())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's perfect!